# How to use variable used in ng-repeat in same line?

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of colors in my controller. I want to generate a table where rows will have background color same as that of each element in the color.

I already wrote CSS to generate the color. I just want `{{color}}` to render color in the array.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="color in colors" class="{{color}}">
        <td>Some dummy text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I know if we use `{{color}}` in `<td>` I can have the same result. But I need to use it in the same line. I am wondering if that is possible or not.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you want `ng-class="color"`.

Comment: Excellent! That worked.. thank you @Claies

Comment: I don't see why you needed to change anything- I whipped up a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/VdYBU5rbpPzFuPNW9dTI?p=preview) that uses your exact html and it works just fine.

Comment: @Danny You are right!! I used only "color" before and not "{{color}}". My bad.. Thanks anyway!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although, what @Claies told you about `ng-class` is correct but your code is working even with `class`:

```js
angular.module('sa', []).controller('Foo', function($scope) {
  $scope.colors = ['red', 'green'];
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="Foo">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="color in colors" class="{{color}}">
      <td>Some dummy text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ng-style`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle), which allows you to interpolate a style inline. I have created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jqwf8dpf/4/

HTML:

```
<table ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <tr ng-repeat="color in colors" ng-style="{ 'background-color': '{{color}}' }">
        <td>Some dummy text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Code:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
});
```

Comment: As you can see this method allows you to avoid having a CSS class for every color you want, making the code dry. IMO the best way to do this.